# Why when running spark in local mode do I need to perform a read using the DataFrames API to authenticate with AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

This code works and passes:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AWSCredentials h = new AWSCredentials();
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .setAppName("Test")
                .set("fs.s3a.access.key", h.access_key_id)
                .set("fs.s3a.secret.key", h.secret_access_key);
        if (h.session_token != null) {
            conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider");
            conf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", h.session_token);
        }
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
        long count = spark.read().text("s3a://mybucket/path-to-files/file+9+0000000223.bin").javaRDD().count();
        System.out.println("count from scala spark is: " + count);
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        JavaRDD<String> maxwellRdd = sc.textFile("s3a://mybucket/path-to-files/*");
        System.out.println("count is: " + maxwellRdd.count());

        sc.stop();
    }
}
```

This code fails with the AWS credentials provider exception below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AWSCredentials h = new AWSCredentials();
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .setAppName("Test")
                .set("fs.s3a.access.key", h.access_key_id)
                .set("fs.s3a.secret.key", h.secret_access_key);
        if (h.session_token != null) {
            conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider");
            conf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", h.session_token);
        }
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
        //long count = spark.read().text("s3a://mybucket/path-to-files/file+9+0000000223.bin").javaRDD().count();
        //System.out.println("count from scala spark is: " + count);
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        JavaRDD<String> maxwellRdd = sc.textFile("s3a://mybucket/path-to-files/*");
        System.out.println("count is: " + maxwellRdd.count());

        sc.stop();
    }
}
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.InterruptedIOException: doesBucketExist on mybucket: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials from Amazon EC2 metadata service`

This seems pretty weird to me. I would've expected 1. the JavaSparkContext and the SparkSession to use the same authentication methods and providers. 2. if the SparkSession were to use a different authentication method, I'm surprised that it apparently does so in some sort of side-effectful way that sets up a connection for the JavaSparkContext to use.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.ini4j', name: 'ini4j', version: '0.5.4'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-aws', version: '2.8.3'
    //compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.313'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not convinced your first one worked —more specifically, if it does work, it's because something is picking your credentials from environment variables or EC2 IAM settings.

If you are trying to set s3a options in spark conf, you need to prefix every option with `"spark.hadoop."`

Simple test: after creating the spark context, call `sc.hadoopConfiguration` and look for the options there (which are all defined in `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants` if you want to be 100% sure you've not got any typos.

Comment: well the first one does definitely work in terms of it reads the files, presumably because it's reading by ~/.aws/credentials I guess though even that seems odd (there's no default profile). Aaaanyway you're totally right that the options need to be prepended with spark.hadoop. That fixes it. Cheers.

Comment: I doubt it'd pick up from ~/aws/credentials, but if you have the AWS_ env vars set, spark-submit grabs them and converts them to the fs.s3n/s3a properties automatically. Good to see things work